# Syncing Avengers Alliance accounts?

Tags: marvel-avengers-alliance

I played Avengers Alliance on Facebook for a long time (though it's been a little more than a year) and had made a bunch of progress and unlocked a fair number of heroes. 
I recently decided I wanted to play again, so I downloaded the game onto my phone. Unfortunately, I can't find an option that will let me sync the amount on my phone with the one on my Facebook account. 
Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: If you want to play it on your phone, however, check out the Puffin browser.  It's cloud based and allows you to use flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

The Version of the game for Facebook is **different** than the Mobile Version.

The Facebook Version cannot be synced with The Mobile Version.